# How to make a plain text-only Silverlight button?

Tags: silverlight

I simply want a button with no background or anything other than plain text. I have done the following and the button does not show up at all:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="linkButtons" TargetType="Button">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="28" FontFamily="Verdana" Padding="10"></TextBlock>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Button Template="{StaticResource linkButtons}" Content="Hello World!"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a button is designed to have content, not text - it's a kind of ContentControl.  So, to display the content, your template should have this in it:

```
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
```

***OR***, you could make a custom control based on button, add a Text property to it, use your current TextBlock control in the template (but with `Text="{Binding Text}"`) and leave the ContentPresenter out of your template.  Making a custom control is a little trickier than just making a template for an existing one, but it's really the best way to get exactly what you're going for.

Comment: I must not be doing something right.. it's not working for me

Answer (score 5):

This is because the `TextBlock` inside the Control template does not have a template binding. Make an attribute like this:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="28" FontFamily="Verdana" Padding="10" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

Not sure if thats the correct syntax, but thats the concept.

Comment: that makes sense but you're right the syntax is off.. "Content" isn't an option

Comment: It is.  Content is a property of Button.  It won't show up in the intellisense, though.